# LLVM : Create an Instruction from its opcode

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I'm looking for a way to create an LLVM [Instruction](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Instruction.html) from its opcode.
The ideal function would be something such as `Instruction *createInstruction(unsigned Opcode, ArrayRef<Value *> Operands);`

Is there anything like it ?
Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at [AsmParser](https://llvm.org/doxygen/AsmParser_8cpp.html), a small part of what it does is the thing you want.

Comment: @arnt, that's the wrong AsmParser surely? That's parsing native machine code assembly files as part of MCParser?

Comment: I don't think there is one? There's BinaryOperator::Create which handles add/fadd/sub/fsub/mul/fmul/udiv/sdiv/fdiv/urem/srem/frem/shl/lshr/ashr/and/or/xor and there's CastInst::create for trunc/zext/sext/fptoui/fptosi/uitofp/sitofp/fptrunc/fpext/ptrtoint/inttoptr/bitcast/addrspacecast and there's CmpInst::create for icmp/fcmp and that's it. I think you'll need to write your own switch statement, but you can at least use the trick of `#include "llvm/IR/Instruction.def"` to help you cut down on lines of code.

Comment: Oh, crap. I meant the AsmParser used by [llvm-as.cpp](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/llvm/tools/llvm-as/llvm-as.cpp). llvm-as converts .ll to .bc, so the kind of asm it reads has to be the kind that contains the opcodes op325 wants to handle.

Comment: Anyway, setting a breakpoint on BinaryOperator::Create() while running llvm-as in a debugger ought to find the function that parses an opcode name and creates a BinaryOperator (or other Instruction) very quickly.